# vethernet doesn't show up in get-netconnectionprofile anymore

Tags: windows-10, networking, powershell, hyper-v

Last night my windows rebooted to install updates and is running 1903 18362.1016

I need to set my hyper-v vEthernet adapter to a private network. However when I do

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-netconnectionprofile


Name             : home-wireless-1
InterfaceAlias   : WiFi
InterfaceIndex   : 12
NetworkCategory  : Public
IPv4Connectivity : Internet
IPv6Connectivity : NoTraffic



PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-netadapter

Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       MacAddress             LinkSpeed
----                      --------------------                    ------- ------       ----------             ---------
vEthernet (Default Swi... Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter             25 Up           00-15-5D-19-34-83        10 Gbps
WiFi                      Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-N 7260           12 Up           0C-8B-FD-61-A8-D2       270 Mbps
Ethernet 2                TAP-Windows Adapter V9                        8 Disconnected 00-FF-2C-9E-4B-96        10 Mbps
Ethernet                  Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM          6 Disconnected E0-18-77-DD-D8-F6          0 bps


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-NetConnectionProfile -interfaceindex 25 -networkcategory private
Set-NetConnectionProfile : No MSFT_NetConnectionProfile objects found with property 'InterfaceIndex' equal to '25'.
Verify the value of the property and retry.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-NetConnectionProfile -interfaceindex 25 -networkcategory private
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (25:UInt32) [Set-NetConnectionProfile], CimJobException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound_InterfaceIndex,Set-NetConnectionProfile

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

It says there is no `MSFT_NetConnectionProfile object` with interface index 25, even though `get-netadapter` shows vEthernet is `25`

Has something changed? `get-netconnectionprofile` used to show my vethernet adapter, but now it only shows the wifi

Comment: Have you found out how to resolve this issue? Maybe a workaround?

Comment: no, have not resolved the issue. As I am unable to make the network a private one (and hence trusted by Windows firewall), I just turn the firewall off when I need to access the internet from it. Not a great one, but its all I can do until I find a fix

Comment: OK, a pity, thank you for your quick reply though!