# Share folder between Hyper-V host and guest - keep it available when not connected

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, sharing

I've a directory **on my host machine** with a Hyper-V guest OS accessing it and it works just fine as long as I'm connected via vmconnect.exe to the guest. As soon as I disconnect (even though the VM is still running) the share is automatically disconnected as well.

Is there a way to create a share that is kept alive?

Comment: If the guest is the share's server, manually configure the share's server to start at guest boot, then configure the host to connect to the share normally via ≥ SMBv2. If you're already done so, and a private adapter has been added to the guest _(an SMB user will need to be added on the host and guest if not using the Windows user's name on the guest)_, you'll need to install OpenVPN, specifically for it's TAP adapter since Windows doesn't support vLANs. Add a 2nd TAP adapter, setting it to always connect and assigning it a static IP within the same subnet as the guest's private adapter vLAN.

Comment: See if doing it via the 'accepted' answer here helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41264525/hyper-v-create-shared-folder-between-host-and-guest-with-internal-network - Not the enhanced session way, the other way.

Comment: I'm working the other way round. The host has the actual directory and wants to share it to the guest VM. I'm going to adjust the question.

Comment: The same concept basically applies the other way around but I didn't read it all the way thru initially. Basically, confirm that both can access the network of the other via ping and then on the Host Hyper-V server, create the folder and share it accordingly. It should then work just like any other type of shared folder. If not, you might indicate how you have the network configured within Hyper-V for the guest machine. The enhanced session method appears to apply only when connected to the VM so set it up the standard way as if it were not a VM accessing via Hyper-V settings

Comment: See here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4092694/windows-10-file-sharing-over-a-network. Let us know what you might have trouble with upon getting this configured this way.

Comment: By configuring the network adapter as a "Private network" within the VM, I can reach shares on the VM from the host now. But I want to do it the other way round. However, I cannot make the network connection of the "vEthernet (Default Switch)" a private network. The PowerShell cmdlet `Get-NetConnectionProfile` shows only my Internet connection. Looks like the description in https://superuser.com/questions/1578302/vethernet-doesnt-show-up-in-get-netconnectionprofile-anymore - do you have an idea how to workaround this?

Comment: (If I disable the Windows Firewall on the host everything works out, but I don't want to do that, I just want to mark the network between them as a Private one and let Windows do the trick)

Comment: As a workaround I allowed inbound SMB file sharing on public networks now too, but that's not what I want to do at all if I'm in some Internet cafe. So I need to know how to set the Hyper-V switch to a private network.